# Autoload library in bundle of Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, simplesamlphp

I have a centralized installation of [SimpleSAMLphp](https://github.com/simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp) in my server on path `/var/simplesamlphp`. I want to use this library in my Symfony2 reusable bundle for authentication.

What would be the proper way of autoloading this library? Should I leave the autoloading for Composer?

Or maybe there is some way to autoload it in my bundle so that the path where the library is placed would be configurable in bundle configuration?

The purpose of autoloading is to be able to inject library classes in services of the bundle and work out the problem without `require '/var/simplesamlphp/lib/_autoload.php'`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to stick with the centralized installation? That library is found on Packagist and can be used with Composer. It will take care of autoloading as well.

Comment: It is because many applications are using the same instance of the library in the server due to automatic metadata collection and some other features

Comment: Sounds scary. Using a central instance means not being able to update it unless you want to update ALL applications using it at once at the same time. I don't understand why centralized is the reason for data collection. You could collect data no matter where the source code is located. And there is no need to switch all applications at once to use Composer - start with the one you are currently working on.

Comment: It is used for authentication, so the update process is straight forward. It is not the design i chosen. All the applications are calling for the same identity provider, and according to my working place, we should keep the configuration as well as the lib in the same place.

Comment: you can add paths to composers autoloader aswell: [See this article](http://blog.abouthalf.com/development/adding-php-include-paths-to-a-project-managed-by-composer/). If it works for you I can write a separate answer